# Is there an infinite increasing sequence of naturals for which Landau's function can be efficiently computed?

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

[Landau's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function)
$g(n)$ is the largest order of an element of the symmetric group $S_n$.
Equivalently, $g(n)$ is the largest least common multiple (lcm) of any partition of $n$.

In general $g(n)$ is hard to compute and bounds are known.

I am wondering is it possible to compute $g(n)$ efficiently or even
find easy closed form for special cases.

**EDIT** as *Alexander Bors* points out in comment, $\log{g(n)} \sim \sqrt{n\log{n}}$ which makes $g(n)$ exponential in $n$, possibly answering the previous revision.

> Is there an infinite increasing sequence $a(n)$ of naturals for which
>   $g(n)$ can be efficiently computed, assuming one can store $g(a(n))$ in RAM of sufficiently powerful computer?

Comment: Since $\mathrm{log}\hspace{2pt}g(n)\sim\sqrt{n\cdot\mathrm{log}\hspace{2pt}n}$, the number of ciphers of $g(n)$ alone is already too large to allow for computation in time polynomial in $\mathrm{log}\hspace{2pt}n$ on any infinite set of values for $n$.

Comment: If $n$ is the sum of the first $k$ primes, can $g(n)$ be anything other than the product of those primes?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yours would have been very nice, but I think it can be something else: for $n=\sum_{p \le 43}=281$ g(n) factors as `2^4 * 3^2 * 5^2 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19 * 23 * 29 * 31 * 37 * 43`

Comment: @GerryMyerson you can verify this in the OEIS b-file: https://oeis.org/A000793/b000793.txt

Comment: Yes, there's a smaller example at $n=100=2+3+\cdots+23$, where $g(n)=(16)(9)(5)(7)(11)(13)(17)(19)$.

Comment: @AlexanderBors very good point, thanks! Will try to edit to make it saner...

Comment: @GerryMyerson I believe your disproved conjecture contradicts the asymptotic of $g(n)$.